# xml to mysql simplexml_load_string, no insert

Tags: php, mysql

the values are not being inserted and also no error is being displayed. Any idea as to what is happening with my insert?

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<setnames>
<country>
<countryCode>AD</countryCode>
<countryName>Andorra</countryName>
</country>
<country>
<countryCode>AE</countryCode>
<countryName>United Arab Emirates</countryName>
<isoNumeric>784</isoNumeric>
</country>
<country>
<countryCode>AF</countryCode>
<countryName>Afghanistan</countryName>
<isoNumeric>784</isoNumeric>
</country>
</setnames>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml as $country) 
{

mysqli INSERT INTO setnames 
VALUES ($country->countryCode, $country->countryName, $country->isoNumeric);

    echo $country->countryCode . "<br />";
    echo $country->countryName . "<br />";
    echo $country->isoNumeric . "<br />"
}
```

Comment: What shows `var_dump($xml)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xml variable is an object, nor an array. So, you should do your foreach like this:

```
foreach ($xml->country as $country) 
{

mysqli INSERT INTO setnames 
VALUES ($country->countryCode, $country->countryName, $country->isoNumeric);

    echo $country->countryCode . "<br />";
    echo $country->countryName . "<br />";
    echo $country->isoNumeric . "<br />"
}
```